# How to modify Google Cloud Pub/Sub subscription acknowledgement deadline for background Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

When deploying a background Cloud Function for Cloud Pub/Sub via:

`gcloud functions deploy function_name --runtime python37 --trigger-topic some_topic`

A subscription gets automatically created with a push endpoint (likely App Engine standard endpoint, but those are claimed to be without the need of 
 domain verification https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#other-endpoints).

For the generated subscription/endpoint there doesn't seem like a way to register/verify the domain
(https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification, https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/domainverification)

As a result the user cannot alter the subscription, for instance:

`gcloud alpha pubsub subscriptions update some_subscription --ack-deadline=10`

Would yield something like "INVALID_ARGUMENT: The supplied HTTP URL is not registered in the subscription's parent project"

Doing it via the web interface on GCP would also yield an error: "pubsub error INVALID_ARGUMENT"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When connecting to a Cloud Pub/Sub topic via Cloud Functions, a subscription is created on your behalf. This subscription is managed by Cloud Functions and therefore it is not possible to update the acknowledgement deadline.

Comment: Hi Kamal, is this still the case? I'm trying to update my Cloud Function pubsub subscription to use `max-delivery-attempts`. Attempts to do it using `gcloud` get me a similar error to @llompalles, but I was able to make the change through the web console. If this just isn't a supported thing to do, I'll want to find another approach!

Comment: I believe it is still the case, yes. I just tried it and still get the same error, even in the web console. I see an "Error creating subscription" message at the bottom of the page. The only way it works is if I, for example, change the delivery type to "Pull." Then, I can change other properties like the max delivery attempts. However, changing it to "Pull" would mean the messages would no longer be delivered to the Cloud Function.

Comment: Thanks! Plan B it is then!