# How to handle piling up of unacknowledged messages in google background function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

When cloud functions are deployed and linked to a pub/sub topic, a subscription that users cannot edit is created([How to modify Google Cloud Pub/Sub subscription acknowledgement deadline for background Cloud Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55009740/how-to-modify-google-cloud-pub-sub-subscription-acknowledgement-deadline-for-bac))

As a result the unacknowledged message retention deadline is fixed at 7 days.

When a cloud function times out (5 min max of execution time), the message is unacknowledged and the message queue starts to pile up into the thousands.

I tried catching for TimeoutError in the cloud function but it doesn't work.

Is there any proper approach to deal with this issue?

Thanks!

```py
def cloud_function():
    try:
        # do something long
    except TimeoutError:
        # log some message and explicitly return to "ack" the message
        return
```

Comment: Is the >5 min execution time of the cloud function a normal situation?  How long should your cloud function run for?

Comment: @Kolban Not normal but not exactly an error either, there are times where it could be useful to be able to run longer than five. Should users implement some kind of timer internally in the function to exit when it's near the timeout limit?..

Comment: You should definitely implement an internal timer so the function can terminate normally and therefore ack the message as you see fit.

Comment: If we look here, https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas .. we find that cloud functions can only execute for a maximum of 9 minutes before being timed out.  Not sure where 5 is coming from.  The idea behind Cloud Functions is that they are short lived.  If the function is taking longer than  the timeout, then I question whether it is actually a good fit for a cloud function.  Cloud Run has a 15 minute timeout and might be an alternative.  It might be that this is a candidate for longer running compute or can be divided into a pipeline of shorter tasks.

Comment: Oops, you're right it's 9 minutes. I can try that first. The function is very light weight to warrant serving a container like cloud-run. Just the way it's being called in a server-less manner was nice/easy to set up (but maybe it shouldn't run too long)